# Arithmetic functions & logs

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic-functions

How do you simplify the following equation in terms of other arithmetic functions?

$$ f(n)= \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) log(d) ? $$

log(n) is not a multiplicative arithmetic function, so i dont know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

This is (up to the sign) the well known [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Von_Mangoldt_function&redirect=no#Properties) :
$$\Lambda(n)= -\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log(d)$$

Comment: Glad it helped @J.M. !